# Solving a System of four equations (with logs) in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of four equations in four variables. I have read a number of threads on similar issues and tried to follow the suggestions. But I think it is a bit messy because of the logs and cross products here. This is the exact system:

7*w = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * ( 0.76 + 0.12*Log[w] -0.08*Log[x] -0.03*Log[y] -0.07*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
5*x = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * ( 0.84 - 0.08*Log[w] +0.11*Log[x] -0.02*Log[y] -0.08*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
2*y = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * (-0.45 - 0.03*Log[w] -0.02*Log[x] +0.05*Log[y] +0.12*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
1*z = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * (-0.16 + 0*Log[w] - 0*Log[x] - 0*Log[y] + 0.03*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z])

(FYI-I am a young economist, and this is an extension of a consumer demand system.) Theoretically, we know that there exists a unique solution to this system that is positive.

**Trys**

- Solve & NSolve : As there should be a solution I tried these but neither works. I guess that the system has too many logs to handle.
- FindRoot : I started with an initial value of (14,15,10,100) which I get from my data. FindRoot returns the last value (which does not satisfy my system) and the following message.

  *FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable.....*

I tried different initial values, including the value returned by FindRoot. I tried to analyze the pattern of the solution value at each step. I didn’t see any pattern but noticed that the z values become negative early in the process. So I put bounds on the values. This just stops the code at the minimum value of 0.1. I also tried an exponential system instead of log, same issues.

```
 Reap[FindRoot[{
 7*w==(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z)*(0.76 + 0.12*Log[w] -0.08*Log[x] -0.03*Log[y] -0.07*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
 5*x==(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z)*(0.84  -0.08*Log[w] +0.11*Log[x] -0.02*Log[y] -0.08*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
 2*y==(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z)*(-0.45 - 0.03*Log[w] -0.02*Log[x] +0.05*Log[y] +0.12*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z]),
 z==(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z)*(-0.16 + 0*Log[w] -0*Log[x] -0*Log[y] +0.03*Log[7*w+5*x + 2*y + z])},
      {{w,14,0.1,500},{x,15,0.1,500},{y,10,0.1,500},        
       {z,100,0.1,500}},EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[{w,x,y,z}] ]]
```

- FindMinimum : As we can write this problem as a minimization problem, I tried this (following the suggestion here). The value returned did not converge the system or equations to zero. I tried with only the first two equations, and that sort of converged to zero.

Hope this is engaging enough for the experts here! Any ideas how I should find the solution or why can’t I? It’s the first time I am using Mathematica, and unfortunately the first time I am empirically solving a system/optimizing! Thanks a lot.

```
{g1,g2,g3, g4}={7*w - (7*w+5*x+2*y+z)* (0.76+0.12*Log[w]-0.08*Log[x]-0.03*Log[y] -0.07*Log[7*w+5*x+2*y+z]),5*x - (7*w+5*x+2*y+z)*(0.84-0.08*Log[w]+0.11*Log[x]-0.02*Log[y] -0.08*Log[7*w+5*x+2*y+z]),2*y - (7*w+5*x+2*y+z)*(-0.45-0.03*Log[w]-0.02*Log[x]+0.05*Log[y]+0.12*Log[7*w+5*x+2*y+z]), 1*z - (7*w+5*x+2*y+z)*(-0.16+0*Log[w]-0*Log[x]-0*Log[y]+0.03*Log[7*w+5*x+2*y+z])};subdomain=0<w<100 &&0<x<100 && 0<y<100 && 0<z<100;res=FindMinimum[{Total[{g1,g2,g3, g4}^2],subdomain},{w,x,y,z},AccuracyGoal->5]{g1,g2,g3,g4}/.res[[2]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Mathematica, I put your equations into [AMPL](http://www.ampl.com/) which is free for students. Here is what I did:

```
var w := 14 >= 0;
var x := 15 >= 0;
var y := 10 >= 0;
var z := 100 >= 0;

eq1: 7*w = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * ( 0.76 + 0.12*log(w) -0.08*log(x) -0.03*log(y) -0.07*log(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z));
eq2: 5*x = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * ( 0.84 - 0.08*log(w) +0.11*log(x) -0.02*log(y) -0.08*log(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z));
eq3: 2*y = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * (-0.45 - 0.03*log(w) -0.02*log(x) +0.05*log(y) +0.12*log(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z));
eq4: 1*z = (7*w+5*x+2*y+z) * (-0.16 +    0*log(w) -   0*log(x) -   0*log(y) +0.03*log(7*w+5*x + 2*y + z));

option show_stats 1;
option presolve 10;
option solver "/home/ali/ampl/ipopt"; # put your path here

option seed 1731;

# Initial solve
solve;
display w, x, y, z;

# Multistart
for {1..10} {
    for {j in 1.._snvars}
        let _svar[j] := Uniform(1, 50);
    solve;
    if (solve_result_num < 200) then {
      display w, x, y, z;
    }
}
```

If I only require that the variables are nonnegative, I get rubbish, for example

```
w = 2.39266e-11
x = 6.62678e-11
y = 1.57043e-24
z = 7.0842e-10
```

or

```
w = 1.09972e-12
x = 9.77807e-11
y = 3.36229e-21
z = 1.85441e-09
```

**Numerically, these are indeed solutions**, they satisfy the equations to a fairly high precision, although I am pretty sure it's not what you are looking for. This indicates issues with your model.

If I increase the lower bounds of the variables a bit:

```
var w := 14 >= 0.1;
var x := 15 >= 0.1;
var y := 10 >= 0.1;
var z := 100 >= 0.01;
```

I get, even with multistart, `Ipopt 3.11.6: Converged to a locally infeasible point. Problem may be infeasible.` This again indicates issues with your model equations.

I am afraid you will have to revise your model.

---

This won't fix the issues with your model equations but I would introduce new variables: `a=log(w), b=log(x), c=log(y), d=log(z)`. Then `w=exp(a)` and so on. It has the advantage that the function evaluations won't fail due to negative arguments for the logarithm function.

I would probably also introduce a new variable for `(7*w+5*x+2*y+z)` just to make the equations more compact.

Neither of these new variables will solve the above issues with your model equations.

---

If it is really your first time using Mathematica, you might be better off with AMPL and [IPOPT](http://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/); these tools are custom-tailored for solving equations and optimization problems. I suggest you use the [AMPL mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/ampl) if you have question and not Stackoverflow; you will get better answers on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very useful. The 'multistart' option is neat as I was doubting my initial values. 
I was very convinced about the model, so I tried a system of two equations. This sometimes gives less rubbish solutions like (w=1, x=4), but it is sensitive to changes in coefficients and the solution to w is always 1 for some reason.
I'll get on to AMPL! Thanks again.

Comment: @Divergent-Economist Your welcome; don't forget to chose an answer and accept it. And good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This method will often rapidly find approximate solutions, NMinimize the sum of squares with constraints.

```
In[2]:= NMinimize[{
   (7*w - (7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z)*(0.76 + 0.12*Log[w] - 0.08*Log[x] - 
     0.03*Log[y] - 0.07*Log[7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z]))^2 +
   (5*x - (7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z)*(0.84 - 0.08*Log[w] + 0.11*Log[x] - 
     0.02*Log[y] - 0.08*Log[7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z]))^2 +
   (2*y - (7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z)*(-0.45 - 0.03*Log[w] - 0.02*Log[x] + 
     0.05*Log[y] + 0.12*Log[7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z]))^2 +
   (1*z - (7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z)*(-0.16 + 0*Log[w] + 
     0.03*Log[7*w + 5*x + 2*y + z]))^2, 
   w > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {w, x, y, z}, 
   Method -> "RandomSearch"]

Out[2]= {9.34024*10^-12, {w->1.86998*10^-8, x->3.83383*10^-8, y->4.59973*10^-8, z->5.29581*10^-7}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense to look for global minimum using this! Though as Ali pointed out these solution values are not the ones I hoped to see. But at least your method is ensuring me that I haven't missed out on solutions to the system.

Comment: I am always skeptical and I would have to think about that a lot longer before I could be convinced there were no other solutions than the one near zero. I don't know that the implementation details of RandomSearch are really documented so I still worry about this. But this technique seems to usually be fast and find a solution when other methods sometimes grind away until infinity.